# jquery sticky Footer: it comes from top of page instead from bottom page

Tags: jquery, sticky-footer

I Have edited [Sticky Footer script](http://codershelpdesk.com/2012/04/13/jquery-sticky-footer-example-with-demo/)  in this way:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    function stickyFooter(){
            jQuery("#stickyFooter").css({position: "absolute",top:($(window).scrollTop()+$(window).height()-$("#stickyFooter").height())+"px"});
    }

    function myStickyFooter(){
            jQuery("#stickyFooter").css({position: "absolute"});
            jQuery("#stickyFooter").animate({
            top:($(window).scrollTop()+$(window).height()-$("#stickyFooter").height())+"px"
          }, 2000, function() {
          });
    }

    jQuery(function(){

        myStickyFooter();
        jQuery(window)
            .scroll(stickyFooter)
            .resize(stickyFooter);
    });
</script>
```

So, on firefox it works fine; on Chrome or Ie, it works .. conversely: stickyFooter appears from top to bottom page. Why?
Thanks a lot!

Comment: Where is the HTML? http://jsfiddle could be even better.

Comment: Did you know you can set "bottom" as a CSS attribute instead of "top"?

Answer (score 2):

This works with all browsers.

SOLUTION:

You need to put up extra work to set initial position of sticky footer to `window.height()` and then animate it up to `window.height()-($('#footer').height())`